# How do I determine the proper probability for a chance-based reward system?

Tags: probability

Let's say I have game of chance with a number of players (1000), with each player having a chance to win something (\$25 for this example.) What probability to win would each player need in order to pay out no more than $1000 over a 30 day period? Each player would be allowed to play 5 times per day. What formula is used to calculate this?

Not a Math major, so I'm not sure of the proper way to phrase the question. Please correct the title and question as appropriate.

Comment: So, you could have up to 150,000 attempts a month?  And you want to limit it to 40 wins?  Really, there is no probability that "guarantees" no more than 40 wins will occur without stepping in and shutting it down.  But there are certain levels of confidence that you can achieve.

Comment: @turkeyhundt I think that's on the right track for what I'm looking for. So not a guarantee, but confidence levels. How would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well then you need to think about the binomial coefficient (i.e., P(k successes in n trials) = ${n\choose k}$$p^kq^{n-k}$ where p is the probability of success and q the probability of failure in one trial). So, for example, Given a 4% chance of win, the chance of 30 wins is ${150000\choose30}0.04^{30}0.96^{150000-30}$, which is difficult on most calculators due to the sheer size of the binomial coefficient. Less trials would be much easier to compute.

Comment: I believe this is the answer I was looking for. In order to check 29, 28, etc. I assume I can just substitute the 30 for those. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, just swap the 30 for however many wins you want. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

As turkeyhundt said, you have a maximum of 150000 attempts a month. Now, your maximum payout in a month is £1000, so at £25 per win thats a maximum of 1000/25 = 40 wins per month. So you can have a maximum of 40 wins in 150000 maximum attempts, so the maximum chance each individual play could have is 40/150000. But, each player can have 5 plays a day for 30 days, so each player can have a total of 30x5=150 plays. So each player has a maximum of 150 individual plays, so the maximum chance a player can have of winning is 150x(40/150000) = 40/1000 = 0.04

Comment: This gets close to what I'm looking for, but I'm still trying to determine how I get the probabilities for other values. Given these odds, what is the probability for 30 wins instead of 40? How about 50? Maybe rephrased: "given 150000 attempts, what are the probabilities of different numbers of wins, given a 4% chance of win per attempt? What is the chance of 40 wins? What is the chance of 50?" Thank you.

Comment: Give me 2 minutes and I'll add this as another answer; it requires too many symbols to be trying to do it in the comments